# Getting multiple streams from two SSLSockets (Client side)

Tags: java, android, ssl, handshake

I have a Android client application and a normal Java server, both with SSL encryption. On the server side I set up SSLServerSockets, one for data and one for special async instructions to the client and otherwise. Here is the code for SSLServerSocket set up:

SSLServerSocket set up:

```
Security.addProvider(new Provider());

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", GlobalVariables.KEYSTORE_PATH);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", Server.KEY_STORE_PW);

sslServerSocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

// Enable debugging to view the handshake and communication which happens between the SSLClient and the SSLServer
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

try
{
  serverDataSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketfactory.createServerSocket(Server.SERVER_DATA_PORT);
  serverStatusSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketfactory.createServerSocket(Server.SERVER_STATUS_PORT);

  waitForClients();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  Log.error(ServerAgent.class, "Establishing ServerSocket was not successful.", e);
}
```

After this, I wait for clients to connect in the waitForClients() method you can see here:

```
while (serverModel.isServerRunning())
{
  try
  {
    clientDataSocket = (SSLSocket) serverDataSocket.accept();
    clientStatusSocket = (SSLSocket) serverStatusSocket.accept();

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        Client client = new Client(clientDataSocket, clientStatusSocket, iliasSoapClient, serverModel.getTimeoutServer());

        if (client.manageHandshake())
        {
          serverModel.addClient(client);
        }
      }
    }).start();
  }
  catch (SocketException e)
  {
    Log.warn(ServerAgent.class, "Close was invoked by an external method, so now the server is shutting down...", e);
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    Log.error(ServerAgent.class, "Can not get the Socket from the ServerSocket.", e);
  }
}
```

On client side I just first connect to the serverDataSocket and after that to the serverStatusSocket with this code:

```
  public boolean connect()
  {
    try
    {
      dataServerSocket = (SSLSocket)sslSocketFactory.createSocket();
      dataServerSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
      dataServerSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(Server.SERVER_IP, Server.SERVER_DATA_PORT), 10000);
      dataInput = new Scanner(dataServerSocket.getInputStream());
      dataOutput = new PrintWriter(dataServerSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
      Log.e(Client.class.getName(), "Cannot connect to host with IP: " + Server.SERVER_IP + " under data port: " + Server.SERVER_DATA_PORT + ".", e);
      return false;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      Log.e(Client.class.getName(), "Common IOException: Cannot connect to host with IP: " + Server.SERVER_IP + " under data port: "
          + Server.SERVER_DATA_PORT + ".", e);
      return false;
    }

    try
    {
      statusServerSocket = (SSLSocket)sslSocketFactory.createSocket();
      statusServerSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
      statusServerSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(Server.SERVER_IP, Server.SERVER_STATUS_PORT), 10000);
      statusInput = new Scanner(statusServerSocket.getInputStream());
      statusOutput = new PrintWriter(statusServerSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

      return true;
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
      Log.e(Client.class.getName(), "Cannot connect to host with IP: " + Server.SERVER_IP + " under status port: " + Server.SERVER_STATUS_PORT + ".", e);
      return false;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      Log.e(Client.class.getName(), "Common IOException: Cannot connect to host with IP: " + Server.SERVER_IP + " under status port: "
          + Server.SERVER_STATUS_PORT + ".", e);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I get the following exceptions if I try to retrieve the InputStream as client from the server. Don't know why:

```
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098): Common IOException: Cannot connect to host with IP: 192.168.0.6 under data port: 51234.
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:398)
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:658)
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:629)
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client.connect(Client.java:64)
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at de.hska.ilias.app.client.LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginTask.java:82)
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at de.hska.ilias.app.client.LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginTask.java:1)
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-04 22:34:07.130: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098): Common IOException: Cannot connect to host with IP: 192.168.0.6 under data port: 51234.
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:398)
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:658)
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:629)
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client.connectLocally(Client.java:109)
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at de.hska.ilias.app.client.LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginTask.java:93)
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at de.hska.ilias.app.client.LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginTask.java:1)
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-04 22:34:17.200: E/de.hska.ilias.app.client.Client(29098):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

The SSL handshake timed out. You would have to look at the server log to see why, possibly at the javax.net.debug=ssl,handshake output. You've set the read timeout as ten seconds, which is rather short anyway, but especially for the handshake. I would call `startHandshake()` first and then `setSoTimeout(),` and/or use a longer timeout for the handshake.

**BUT** unless this server is only ever going to service one client, the entire strategy is risky. If two clients connect at the same time, you're in danger of treating the connection from the second client as the second connection from the first client, or vice versa.

Comment: Can you give an example how to hold multiple async streams for one client?

Comment: The problem is not the timeout. I am testing it in LAN. The thing is, if I just try it with one socket, it works fine (SSL handshake), but if I do it like mentioned above, it prints out the message above. Do I need to generate two certificates for both sockets or is one just enough.